# UglifyJS Can't use regex

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

From [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), I can't seem to use this

```
uglifyjs mtool.js -c -m --mangle-props regex=/_$/ -o mtool.min.js
```

as it produces an error:

> ERROR: regex.test is not a function
>       at should_mangle (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :10864:29)
>       at add (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :10874:14)
>       at TreeWalker.eval [as visit] (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :10820:13)
>       at TreeWalker._visit (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :1213:24)
>       at AST_ObjectKeyVal._walk (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :1049:24)
>       at AST_Object.eval (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :1036:31)
>       at TreeWalker._visit (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :1217:21)
>       at AST_Object._walk (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :1033:24)
>       at AST_Call.eval (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :902:25)
>       at TreeWalker._visit (eval at  (C:\Users\Doge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:21:1), :1217:21)

Did I miss installing dependency or something? I tried searching for this but can't find any references to solve the problem.

All's fine. I can uglify my script(s) without problem up until I add regex argument. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you create an issue in the project? https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solely using,

```
regex=/myExpression/
```

will not work.

In using the regex parameter given that uglifyJS version, the value should be a complete expression.

```
regex='/^stackoverflow$/g;'
```

It successfully uglified my target variables accordingly.